# P-adic representations

Tags: p-adic-analysis, galois-representations, nt.number-theory

Hi,
  I am reading about p-adic representations from Fontaine's book which can be found at http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yiouyang/research.html. On page 145
where they prove Proposition 5.24 which is essentially the theorem
of Tate-Sen, they show $H^{n}(Gal(L/K_{\infty},C(i)^{G_L})=0$ and
the argument is essentially same as in the proof of hilbert Thm 90. But
then they are concluding that implies $H^{n}(H_K,C(i))=0$ by passing to the
limit. I am confused because I thought that you can only pass through
the limit in case of discrete modules. I think this same argument will
also show that $H^{1}(G_K,C_K)=0$ which is not true. I am sure I am missing something obvious. I will greatly appreciate any kind of clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole thing is done with more details in Tate's original article "p-divisible groups", section 3.2. Tate proves that one can approximate a cocyle in $C_p(i)$ by cocyles with values in $Q_p^{alg}(i)$ and this is how he reduces the computation to the "discrete case".

I would suggest that it's better to prove the result by $p$-adic approximation. This way, you can basically work with cocycles with values in $O_{C_p}(i)/p^n$, also a discrete space.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Prof. Berger for the reply.I can understand Tate's proof but somehow I did not understand the proof from the book. I think I can prove it by working in O$_{\bar{K}}/p^{n}$. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

They are using continuous cohomology, so that
$$
H^n(G,M) = \varinjlim H^n(G/H,M^H)
$$
if $G$ is topological and $M$ is discrete (*thanks Arjit*) $G$-module (the limit runs over open compact subgroups $H$ of $G$). Look in p. 38 for the definition.

Comment: But this is only true if M is discrete. But this is not the case here.